# Finding element(s) by data attribute = variable using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

Using (custom) jQuery `data-attributes` to retrieve the elements where these icons are displayed, I am successfully changing icons with this working code:

```html
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" data-year="2014" data-flag_check="1"></i>
...
<script>
   ...
   $('i[data-year="2014"]').removeClass('glyphicon-check').addClass('glyphicon-unchecked');
```

But, if I attempt to replace the constant `2014` with a variable, my code stops working.

```
var yearIn = "2014";
$('i[data-year=yearIn]').removeClass('glyphicon-check').addClass('glyphicon-unchecked');
```

Is it possible to perform this operation with a variable?

If so, what is wrong in my syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're just missing string concatenation:

```
var yearIn = "2014";
$('i[data-year=' + yearIn + ']').removeClass('glyphicon-check').addClass('glyphicon-unchecked');
// ------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or in ES2015+ you could use a template literal with a substitution token:

```
  var yearIn = "2014";
  $(`i[data-year=${yearIn}]`).removeClass('glyphicon-check').addClass('glyphicon-unchecked');
//  ^------------^^^^^^^^^-^
```

---

FWIW, I always use quotes around the value in the selector when it comes from a variable, just in case the variable ends up with something in it with spaces, etc.:

```
var yearIn = "2014";
$('i[data-year="' + yearIn + '"]').removeClass('glyphicon-check').addClass('glyphicon-unchecked');
// ------------^--------------^
```

or

```
var yearIn = "2014";
$(`i[data-year="${yearIn}"]`).removeClass('glyphicon-check').addClass('glyphicon-unchecked');
// ------------^---------^
```

Comment: Or use template literals :)

Comment: @Vucko: Quite. I really should start mixing those in, two years later...

Answer (score 2):

You are using the string literal `'yearIn'` rather than the variable `yearIn`. Do something like this to concatenate the strings:

```
$('i[data-year=' + yearIn + ']').removeClass('glyphicon-check').addClass('glyphicon-unchecked');
```